# Magento 2 - code-migration XML_SERIALIZE issue

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1, xml

I am trying to use the code-migration tool provided officialy by magento2 to test the migration from M1 to M2 for extensions.

I setup everything great -composer,folders and so on-

I run the first command which is the convert

```
php bin/migrate.php migrateModuleStructure <src> <dst> - Migrate directory structure
```

and it works great. When i get to the second command

```
php bin/migrate.php convertLayout <dst> - Migrate layout
```

I get a fatal_error

> Error: Class 'XML_Serializer' not found in
>   /home/test/public_html/src/Magento/Migration/Command/ConvertLayout.php
>   on line 211

Any thoughts? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install PEAR package:

```
pear channel-update pear.php.net
pear install channel://pear.php.net/XML_Serializer-0.21.0
```

and then it will work.
See [same problem mentioned here](https://github.com/magento/code-migration/issues/83) and [more about XML_Serializer here](https://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer).

Comment: Thank you, i will try this today and i will let you know the results.

Comment: i cannot select this answer as solved because of low rep but i want to thank you Mihai. I had already installed XML_Serializer so the real problem was a bit different. I had to do the dependencies updates because i was running on php7 after i did that i was able to get it to work. Thank you!!